# How to use command "at" in shell to call zenity in ubuntu

Tags: linux, shell, ubuntu, zenity

I am trying to write a shell script to remind an user. I want to show dialog at a specific time.

I use zenity to show the dialog message

Here is my script

```
#!bin/bash
PATH=/bin:/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin:~/bin
export PATH
at now <<EOF
/bin/zenity --info --text="hello word"
EOF
```

But it doesn't show anything

Please help me.

Comment: (a) Your shebang line is malformed: should be `#!/bin/bash`; (b) what happens when you run the `zenity` command directly? (`/bin` is an unusual location for `zenity` - also, why would it not be in the `$PATH`?).

Comment: (a)but I only wrote  '#!bin/bash'  it work fine

(b)I command <pre>zenity --info --text="hello word"<code>  it will pop a message box directly.

Comment: If you try to run your script directly with this shebang (assuming you've made it executable), it won't run. If you invoke `bash` explicitly and pass it the script as an argument, it will work fine (the 1st line will then be just another comment). As for the actual issue: Seems to me that @abannerth's answer is the correct solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the command executed by `at` isn't executed in the same shell, and in the same environment (where you already have a graphical display available), you will also need to specify which display to use, e.g. by setting the `DISPLAY` environment variable when using zenity:

```
DISPLAY=:0.0 zenity --info --text="hello world"
```

Also, if you're running zenity by writing its absolute path, make sure it's really there. For me, on Ubuntu 14.04 zenity is installed under `/usr/bin/zenity`, so with your example it wouldn't work.